# How do I send bytes to a serial device in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a device that uses serial (via a USB adaptor) to interface with my PC. I'm having real difficulty getting it to play nicely in C#. I know that it works properly because the vendor-supplied software behaves as expected. I also know that I am able to receive data using my code thanks to a test mode which repeatedly sends "OK".

Here's my code:

```
    private SerialPort port;

    public SerialConnection()
    {
        this.port = new SerialPort("COM3", 38400, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        this.port.WriteTimeout = 2000; port.ReadTimeout = 2000;

        this.port.Open();

        this.port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
    }

    public void SendCommand(byte[] command)
    {
        this.port.Write(command,0,command.Length);
        string chars = "";
        foreach (byte charbyte in command) chars += (char)charbyte;
        Console.WriteLine(" -> " + chars);
    }

    void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string data = this.port.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" <- " + data);
    }
```

At the moment I'm using another test mode which is supposed to echo back whatever it receives. Accordingly, I'm calling SendCommand with the following bytes:

```
byte[] {
    0x50,
    0x69,
    0x6E,
    0x67
}
```

But nothing ever seems to get sent back.

I've no idea what to try next. Anyone got any suggestions?

---

For a subsidiary question I've posted some PortMon logs. I think they might be useful here too, so here they are:

1. [Vendors software](http://tdwright.co.uk/minibird_filtered.log) - with all the `IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_COMMSTATUS` entries filtered out
2. [My toe-dip attempt](http://tdwright.co.uk/myapp.log)

Comment: I might recommend downloading Free Serial Port Monitor (http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/).  (Ignore the $12 part, there is a download link on the left.)  It monitors calls to the serial drives somehow and has been quite useful to me in debugging serial issues like this.  You might find that the device is actually sending data back, and your buffer receive threshold is just set to high or something.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I tried that and found that it is not sending anything back. It's a great utility.

Comment: You should read up more on the protocol at hand.  I suspect you are missing something.  If it is helpful to you, use that same utility with the software the device came with, and compare your data to it.  If you are sending the exact same commands, then check the status lines and make sure they are set the same too.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try spying on the provided app before, but when I do it seems to be using the same byte sequences as I'm using. I tried inspecting the pin configuration, but using the `table` view of the serial port monitor is apparently a sure-fire way of crashing my PC.

Comment: @Tom, make sure you disconnect the monitoring software before closing the programs that access the serial port, or unplugging the serial adapter.  There is similar software available... perhaps Franson will give you a free trial:  http://franson.com/serialtools/  In any case, I suspect that your status lines need to be set.

Comment: I would suggest that you tried windows hyperterm first and make sure it works - then try the configuration that worked in hyperterm, if that doesn't work - your code won't work.
Are you sure you are opening the correct COM port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every RS-232 device needs to use some sort of [flow control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control) mechanism to notify the opposite part about ongoing communication. There are three basic mechanisms:

- hardware-based **RTS/CTS** via two dedicated wires, usually used for controlling sending of individual chunks of data
- hardware-based **DTR/DSR** via two dedicated wires, usually used for controlling the whole communication session
- softwa-based **XON/XOFF** via a pair of dedicated characters (note that in this case data needs to be encoded to prevent collisions with control characters)

*(start update)*

Initial queue length and timeouts in the legacy app:

```
1  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_QUEUE_SIZE  InSize: 1024 OutSize: 1024
2  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUT  RI:2000 RM:0 RC:2000 WM:0 WC:2000
```

while you don't set them. Try setting the queue sizes using [`SerialPort.WriteBufferSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.writebuffersize.aspx) and [`SerialPort.ReadBufferSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize.aspx). Likewise set timeouts using [`SerialPort.ReadTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readtimeout.aspx) and [`SerialPort.WriteTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.writetimeout.aspx).

*(end update)*

In your case the legacy app does:

```
12  IOCTL_SERIAL_CLR_RTS
13  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_DTR
```

while you do:

```
12  IOCTL_SERIAL_CLR_RTS
13  IOCTL_SERIAL_CLR_DTR
```

You don't set the DTR (Data Terminal Ready) signal and hence the device is not expecting any data or commands on the serial line. Hence set [`SerialPort.DtrEnable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.dtrenable.aspx) to `true`.

Second problem is you don't turn on handshaking. The legacy app does:

```
16  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW  Shake:1 Replace:0 XonLimit:0 XoffLimit:0
18  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_RTS
…
21  IOCTL_SERIAL_CLR_RTS
```

while you do:

```
16  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW  Shake:0 Replace:0 XonLimit:4096 XoffLimit:4096
```

Turn it on by setting [`SerialPort.Handshake`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.handshake.aspx) to [`Handshake.RequestToSend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.handshake.aspx).

Also, you seem to be opening, closing, and reconfiguring the serial port very frequently. Try to setup the port and then use the same instance of `SerialPort` for the whole session. Do not try to reopen it, because you will be causing reconfigurations to the state of the physical port's pins.

Serial communication is not black magic, but it's quite sensitive on setup and various devices require special settings and treatment. Proper timing of commands may be an issue as well.

If you do have some technical documentation for your device, do read it twice and obey it at the first place. At least handshaking modes, commands, etc. should be documented properly.

If you don't have any documentation, try to mitigate differences one by one.

---

**UPDATE:** Sending and receiving data.

You wrote you sent the command `'Ping'` (as decoded from hex to ASCII). However, you don't mention sending and command termination sequence. *Usually* serial devices expect an end-of-line sequence (typically a CR LF) as the termination of the command. Before the device receives a *complete* command including line end, it can't reply.

You are handling the data receive event by calling `ReadLine` — however, at the place you can't expect a full line of data (i.e. including a line end to be able to detect a comlete line). You should inspect the event arguments provided and read the input byte-by-byte.

It's a good idea to create a wrapper class that will provide a tailored send-command, receive-response, send-data, receive-data features. The wrapper will have to internally work asynchronously in respect to the rest of your code. That way you will have a usable custom API and a well-behaved serial port handling.

Note that the `SerialPort.NewLine` property serves the purpose of specifying how a an end-of-line sequence looks like. (In your other question you mentioned you were trying to set it to the set of special characters. That was wrong indeed.)

---

It's been some time I was a serial comm hero (those were the days we had no vmware but two 486-powered PCs and a pair of directly connected modems to develop and debug communication apps :-)), but I hope this helps at least a bit.

Last but not least, some common terminology:

- DTE — Data Terminal Equipment = your comupter
- DCE — Data Communications Equipment = your device, e.g. a modem

Comment: Thanks Ondrej, that's really detailed. Two things though: 1) SerialPort.DtrEnable was set to true when that recording was done. 2) Setting Handshake to RequestToSend causes the first write operation to time out. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's hard to tell without the actual device. Most likely there's something wrong with your flow control setup.

Comment: Once you make the changes, run the monitoring again and compare what changed, and whether the resulting IOCTL sequence is more similar to what you've recorded with the legacy app. Generally, .NET provides a wrapper over the unmanaged API and may not offer the same level of control. Most likely you will manage to get it up and running using pure .NET, but resorting to calls to unmanaged Win32 API may be an option to consider as well.

Comment: Updated my answer to cover timeouts and queue sizes.

Comment: @Tom Wright How is it going? Did you last update regarding sending and receiving data help in moving forward?

Comment: Going well thanks, but in the end the path of least resistance took me another way. Yours was the most comprehensively useful answer whilst I was on my quest though.

Comment: Glad to hear that. It was a nice challenge to dig all that RS-232-related stuff from my head and remember those “good ol' times of modem communications”.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the [Handshake](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.handshake.aspx) property?  Maybe the device requires some handshaking on the control pins before it will accept data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looked promising, but none of the options resulted in a response. For what it's worth, RequestToSend and RequestToSendXonXoff both caused the Write operation to timeout.

Answer (score 1):

You should turn on the RtsEnable or DtrEnable properties, the device will ignore anything you send nor send anything back when it doesn't detect you online from these signals.  Setting the Handshake property to RTS should have done that though.

Beware that the ReadLine() method will block until it gets the NewLine character.  You are not sending one so you won't get one back either.  Using Read() would be a better test.

Do some basic troubleshooting first with a known-to-work program, eliminating wiring problems, wrong baudrate or the device simply not echo-ing back.  Use HyperTerminal or Putty.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. Neither Rts- or DtrEnable helped. I switched to Read() and even though that didn't help either, it seems like good practice. I couldn't get PuTTY to read even the most basic test mode; the one I can get to work in C#. Not sure what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Tom  ,

I have had similar problems,

I am going to place my bet on the fact that **ReadLine()** only returns once it has received a \r\n or **something that .NET believes is a new line.**

In your logs, i dont see Winbird reporting any new line characters, i believe that APP is reading byte by byte, and not waiting for newlines.

So you can send many bytes of data to it, and it will keep on blocking until it receives the correct new line characters.

So give SerialPort.Read a try, by reading 1 byte at a time for starters,

```
public int Read (
byte[] buffer,
int offset,
int count
```

)

If this doesnt fix it, you might want to consider the following

Some of my problems were fixed with adding a few Thread.Sleep()'s because i realized the PC's UARTs are not fast enough to electrically transmit the data over the RS232/RS485 ports correctly, also wait a few milliseconds after opening the port.

I would also advise you to rather create a separate thread to handle the serial comms, instead of using SerialDataReceivedEventHandler, create a send buffer, which is sent in the correct increments without blocking your app, also read the data and append bytes received to buffer until you have received enough data.

You are also going to need a second serial device to capture your data to make sure your C# app is transmitting the correct data.

To elimate the issue of handshaking, test by only having PIN 2,3 + PIN 5 (GND) connected.

Hope this helps