# How do I set serial special characters?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, special-characters

In my [ongoing quest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5504716/50151) to interface with some legacy equipment, I've discovered that the vendor supplied software sets the special characters to:

```
00 00 00 00 11 13
```

But the SerialPort class of .NET set them to:

```
1A 00 00 1A 11 13
```

I suppose that I have two questions:

1. What do these bytes mean?
2. How can I tell SerialPort to use a specific set of special characters?

The latter is all I really care about, but I suspect the former is going to be useful to know.

---

**Update:** The following doesn't work:

```
byte[] specialchars = {
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x11,
    0x13
};

this.port.NewLine = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(specialchars);
```

---

**Update 2:** As requested, here are Portmon logs for [the vendor supplied app](http://tdwright.co.uk/minibird_filtered.log) (filtered to remove the many thousands of IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_COMMSTATUS entries) and for [my attempt to match even the first exchange](http://tdwright.co.uk/myapp.log).

Comment: Use an ASCII table to find those characters: http://www.asciitable.com/  1A corresponds to the Substitute character, see this Wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character

Comment: `0x11` and `0x13` could probably be these http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XON/XOFF

Comment: Thanks guys, they both seem likely. Unfortunately, the only reference to XON/XOFF I can find is a handshake mode. I've already sleuthed the handshake mode and found it to be Handshake.None.

Comment: Could you post a PortMon ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx ) log of a simple connect+request+response with both the code you have and a vendor tool ?

Comment: Hi VirtualBlackFox. PortMon is a surprisingly helpful utility. I'd been using HDD's Free Serial Port Monitor before. Anyway I've uploaded the two log files - can you spot anything useful in there?

Comment: Also, I've put a bounty on the "parent" question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5504716/50151

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NewLine` is not what you are looking for. It's the plain old 'new line' sequence, e.g. CR LF or LF alone.

The special characters are handled like this:

- EOF — set to 0x1a, you cannot change it in .NET
- ERR — set by [`SerialPort.ParityReplace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.parityreplace.aspx)
- BRK — *don't know*
- EVT — set to 0x1a, you cannot change it in .NET
- XON — set to 0x11, you cannot change it in .NET, and it doesn't even usually make sesn
- XOFF — set to 0x13, you cannot change it in .NET, and it doesn't even usually make sesn

It may be helpful for you to study the [Win32 DCB structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well. It's used by .NET internally to set the state of the serial port.

Comment: So it's not possible for me to emulate the vendor supplied software in .NET? I suppose a secondary question is whether or not I need to: What effect could this difference make?

Comment: You are not using XON/XOFF (i.e. software) flow control, so the comm channel is transparent and hence you should not need to worry about the setup of escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extenstion to the serialPort in c# :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/89b88e89-5814-4819-8b50-7caa3faf5f54/xonxoff-values-in-net20-serialport-class?forum=csharpgeneral

for the other fields you can change :

> dcbType.GetField("XonChar"); // "XonChar", "XoffChar", "ErrorChar", "EofChar", "EvtChar"

Code :

```
            using System;
            using System.ComponentModel;
            using System.IO.Ports;
            using System.Reflection;
            using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
            using System.Security;
            using System.Security.Permissions;
            using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    using (var port = new SerialPort("COM1"))
                    {
                        port.Open();
                        port.SetXonXoffChars(0x12, 0x14);
                    }
                }
            }

            internal static class SerialPortExtensions
            {
                [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
                public static void SetXonXoffChars(this SerialPort port, byte xon, byte xoff)
                {
                    if (port == null)
                        throw new NullReferenceException();
                    if (port.BaseStream == null)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot change X chars until after the port has been opened.");

                    try
                    {
                        // Get the base stream and its type which is System.IO.Ports.SerialStream
                        object baseStream = port.BaseStream;
                        Type baseStreamType = baseStream.GetType();

                        // Get the Win32 file handle for the port
                        SafeFileHandle portFileHandle = (SafeFileHandle)baseStreamType.GetField("_handle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(baseStream);

                        // Get the value of the private DCB field (a value type)
                        FieldInfo dcbFieldInfo = baseStreamType.GetField("dcb", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                        object dcbValue = dcbFieldInfo.GetValue(baseStream);

                        // The type of dcb is Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DCB which is an internal type. We can only access it through reflection.
                        Type dcbType = dcbValue.GetType();
                        dcbType.GetField("XonChar").SetValue(dcbValue, xon);
                        dcbType.GetField("XoffChar").SetValue(dcbValue, xoff);

                        // We need to call SetCommState but because dcbValue is a private type, we don't have enough
                        //  information to create a p/Invoke declaration for it. We have to do the marshalling manually.

                        // Create unmanaged memory to copy DCB into
                        IntPtr hGlobal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(dcbValue));
                        try
                        {
                            // Copy their DCB value to unmanaged memory
                            Marshal.StructureToPtr(dcbValue, hGlobal, false);

                            // Call SetCommState
                            if (!SetCommState(portFileHandle, hGlobal))
                                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                            // Update the BaseStream.dcb field if SetCommState succeeded
                            dcbFieldInfo.SetValue(baseStream, dcbValue);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            if (hGlobal != IntPtr.Zero)
                                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hGlobal);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SecurityException) { throw; }
                    catch (OutOfMemoryException) { throw; }
                    catch (Win32Exception) { throw; }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("SetXonXoffChars has failed due to incorrect assumptions about System.IO.Ports.SerialStream which is an internal type.", ex);
                    }
                }

                [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
                private static extern bool SetCommState(SafeFileHandle hFile, IntPtr lpDCB);
            }
```